# Exponential function in C using recursion function

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to CALCULATE the  Exponential function of x   with recursion function .the  Exponential function is calculated from [this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj73h.png) .

I divided the Exponential function for two part the first part which is  [Fracture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qKa3.png)

(i calculated it with the recursion function at the bottom and then put this part in while loop at the main function to find the sum from 0 to N

AS i am beginner in c and my English is not   perfect please explain my Mistake in a SIMPLE WAY .

THANK IN ADVANCE .....

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>

double faktoriyel(double x,double N);

int main(){
    double N, x, a;
    double s = 0;
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    scanf("%lf", &N);
    a = N;
    do
    {
        s += faktoriyel(x, N);
        --a;
    }while (a > 0);
    printf("\n%lf\n", s);
}

double faktoriyel(double x, double N)
{
    if (N < 0)
        return -1;
    else if (N < 2)
        return pow(x, N) / 1;
    else
        return (pow(x, N) / N * faktoriyel(x, N - 1));
}
```

Comment: The necessary images are not visible. Please post your question properly.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS: Newcomers to the site can't post images.  In general, images are not really encouraged anyway, but it isn't entirely fair to blame newcomers for not making them visible.

Comment: Note that there's a bug in the equation you post (the x-squared term has the wrong divisor; it should be 2! and not 1!).  Someone (maybe that was you; given the use of the function name `faktoriyel` in both, it was probably you) posted the same (buggy) equation yesterday too.

Answer (score 0):

Your base case is not right.
It should be

`if(N == 0)
    return 1;`

Why because anything raised to the power 0 is one.So returning 0.

Your method is not proper way of using recursion.
Check this code.

`#include <stdio.h>`

`int power(int n1, int n2);`

`int main()`
`{`
    `int base, powerRaised, result;`

```
`printf("Enter base number: ");`
`scanf("%d",&base);`

`printf("Enter power number(positive integer): ");`
`scanf("%d",&powerRaised);`

`result = power(base, powerRaised);`

`printf("%d^%d = %d", base, powerRaised, result);`
`return 0;`
```

`}`

`int power(int base, int powerRaised)`

`{`
    `if (powerRaised != 0)`

```
    `return (base*power(base, powerRaised-1));`
`else`
    `return 1;`
```

`}`

Answer (score 0):

I changed it a bit here:

```
double faktoriyel(double x,double N) 
{
if (N == 0) return 1;
else return (x/N * faktoriyel(x,N-1));
}
```

why? because you wrote

```
return (pow(x, N) / N * faktoriyel(x, N - 1));
```

which results in caculating
(x^(N+(N-1)+.....+1))/(N!)
instead of x^N/N!.

that is because you recalculate x^N every call to the function
and then multiply it :

(x^N)*(x^(N-1))*....*1

and here:

```
do 
{  
s+=faktoriyel(x,N);
--N;                        
}while (N>=0);
```

instead of this:

```
do
{
    s += faktoriyel(x, N);
    --a;
}while (a > 0);
```

because you actually calculated

x^N/N! + x^N/N! +.....+x^N/N!

instead of :

x^N/N! + x^(N-1)/(N-1)! +.....+1;

decrementing 'a' does not decrement N, resulting
in an incorrect calculation of e^x.

it should work btw.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping ,the result is more accurate but it still not correct , if i entered x=1.23 and N=23 i should  have exp(1.23)=3.41229536     but it is giving me 2.42312

Comment: I wrote down N!=0 instead of N>=0; my bad. it caused the result to be less by 1 from the required result